# Creating Default-Style UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I create a `UIButton`in Swift, e.g. by

```
let aButton = UIButton()
aButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

it seems like I'm not getting the same button style as I would get if I added a button in Interface Builder. Specifically, the title color is white instead of the default "tint color", leaving the button invisible. Now I want this button to look like any other button, so I don't want to specify my own colors.

Setting the normal (not pressed) state can be done with:

```
aButton.setTitleColor(self.tintColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

So far, so good. But the text color does not change when the button is pressed. I guess, for that I need

```
aButton.setTitleColor(/* somehting here */, self.tintColor, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Ideally without hardcoding the color, what do I need to substitute above to get the default pressed button color? Or is there even a simpler way to just create a `UIButton` with default style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to declare a button of the same (default) style as in the storyboard/interface builder, use the following code to instantiate it:

```
let aButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

Otherwise the button is of type `custom`.

You can read about the various button types [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIButtonType).

Comment: ```let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)```

Comment: `let aButton = UIButton(type: .system)`

Comment: @brokenrhino Thanks for pointing this out! Enum values were made lowercase starting Swift 3 in 2016. Will update the answer.